# Jmeter unique session identifier for each time the same test runs

Tags: performance, load, jmeter, load-testing

I would like to know if in Jmeter, I have a test case that I would like to run 3 times a day, is it possible in the jtl or csv output file, if there is a way to identify the test run.
For ex: if I run the test first time for 500 users, the results should specify {some value}  as 1.
And if I run the same test the 2nd time, then results should specify the {some value} as 2
....
....
If I run the same test 50th time, then results should specify the {some value} as 50.

Is it possible we have a solution that we can customize from jmeter properties?
If so please let me know.

Thanks,

Sarathi

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the time function which will simply provide the current timestamp as a variable you can then append to wherever you want.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do it as follows:

1. Pass required property to JMeter via -J command line argument as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -Jiteration=1 -n -t /path/to/test/script.jmx -l /path/to/results/log.jtl
   ```
2. In your test plan refer to that "iteration" property as `${__P(iteration,)}` which will take the value from command line wherever is required:

   - sampler name
   - listener result file
   - test parameter
   - etc.

See screenshot below for the demo

[image: iteration property description]

JMeter properties can also be specified in *jmeter.properties* or *user.properties* files, both usually live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on how to get things done using JMeter properties.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Dmitri. Also could you suggest if I want to set up cron that would run thrice a day, how I would parameterize iteration= <n> on command line?

Comment: The fastest and easiest solution I can think of is to have 3 cron jobs which will write 1, 2 or 3 into a file. Something like `echo 1 > /tmp/jmeter/iteration` and pass this file value to JMeter as `jmeter -Jiteration=$(cat /tmp/jmeter/iteration) -n -t ...`